# History of VanillaJS

Tags: javascript, history

When did the trend of saying VanillaJS to refer to pure JavaScript come into widespread. Is the website [Vanilla-js](http://www.vanilla-js.com) the discoverer of the term VanillaJS or was this term used even before the launch of this website?

Comment: **Ah, the power of satire.**  Check out [comcastify.js](https://theonion.github.io/comcastifyjs/).  You might also enjoy [The Birth and Death of Javascript](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/the-birth-and-death-of-javascript).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I created the Vanilla JS site.

I didn't coin the term "Vanilla JS" - it's like asking someone if they invented the term "Blue Chair".  Blueness and Chairness have been things for thousands of years, and similarly, "Vanilla" in the software world usually means "plain" - Plain JS.  I remember seeing it used before I created the site.

However:

[The Google Trends data for the term "Vanilla JS"](https://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=Vanilla%20JS), which indicates that the term came into widespread use in August 2012, coincides with [the registration date of the vanilla-js.com domain name](http://whois.domaintools.com/vanilla-js.com).  So, while I didn't invent the term, I probably popularized it.  This is funny, since I really don't like the term "vanilla" meaning "plain" - but, it's what the software community uses, so in the interest of clarity (and comedy), it's what I chose to use.

Comment: I think people gravitate towards libraries, at least in part, for the promise of browser independence.  I believe that browser incompatibilities are much less of a problem than they used to be, but the belief in browser quirks (and the faith that people have in jQuery to fix them) still strongly persists.

Comment: If you have to support IE3 and Netscape Navigator, having a framework smooth over differences can help.  If the actual browsers that actually hit your site are latest-Chrome, latest-Firefox, and sufficiently recent IE, in practice, I find the differences are easily managed.  

I suspect many developers use frameworks as a way to avoid learning DOM and similar, but end up instead constantly keeping up with [briefly-valuable skillsets](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/react-hype.jpg) rather than just learning the underlying API.